# C# Selenium webdriver mouseOver. How to freeze appeared object

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, mouseover

Is it possible to freeze appeared object after mouseOver?

e.g. i have an object. When i'm point mouse on it appears a big tooltip with a lot of information that i need to check.

The problem is when i use construction like this:

Actions builder = new Actions(driver); 
Actions hoverOverRegistrar = builder.moveToElement(menuRegistrar); hoverOverRegistrar.perform();

the tooltip appears for a moment and then hides. How to freeze it for a few seconds?

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100000); - does not work

Answer (score 0):

After you move to that particular element, the tooltip is disappearing maybe because the mouse moves after that or the javascript is written like that.

Does it help you if `moveToElement(element).clickAndHold();` ?

Maybe after moving to the element and then click and hold may avoid the tooltip from hiding.